# Lua / Why does adding a new element to a matrix overwrites previously added one?

Tags: arrays, matrix, lua, overwrite, ascii-art

I'm learning Lua, so I decided to try implementing a function that takes co-ordinates from an array and outputs an ASCII picture.

Everything went fine as long as I did't put several dots in a single line (ordinate):

It outputs this

```
...X
.X..
..X.
...X
```

Instead of this

```
XXXX
.X..
..X.
...X
```

After some investigation, I made an conclusion that all local functions work well enough except for `create_massive()`. When it places a dot, previously added in the same y-axis is being removed.

---

To clarify, here's how I came to that conclusion:

I simply removed function `create_massive()` and defined its massive `drawing` myself:

```
local n=nil

drawing={
    {1,1,1,1},
    {n,1,n,n},
    {n,n,1,n},
    {n,n,n,1},
}
```

And the program output what I wanted.

---

### Full code

*I could leave just the function `create_massive()` because only it needs to be fixed but I thought the full code would be more helpful:*

```
function draw(coords,sym,spc)

local sym = sym or "X" -- dot
local spc = spc or "-" -- empty slot

local max={} -- massive containing max co-ordinates
local min={} -- massive containing min co-ordinates
local drawing={} -- massive containing drawing

local function find_min_max()
    -- finds min/max co-ordinates

    for i=1,#coords do
        local c=coords[i]

        if i%2~=0 then
            max.x=max.x and ((c>max.x) and c or max.x) or c
            min.x=min.x and ((c<min.x) and c or min.x) or c
        else
            max.y=min.y and ((c>max.y) and c or max.y) or c
            min.y=min.y and ((c<min.y) and c or min.y) or c
        end
    end

end

local function create_massive()
    -- creates massive containing drawing

    for i=2,#coords,2 do
        local y=coords[i]
        local x=coords[i-1]
        drawing[y]={[x]=1} -- the thing is, it overwrites previous dots' position, so line can contain only the last called dot
    end

end

local function print_drawing()

    local n=1
    local line={}

    for i=min.y,max.y do
        if drawing[i] then
            for k=min.x,max.x do
                if drawing[i][k] then
                    line[n]=line[n] and line[n]..sym or sym
                else
                    line[n]=line[n] and line[n]..spc or spc
                end
                if k==max.x then
                    n=n+1
                end
            end
        else
            for p=min.x,max.x do
                line[n]=line[n] and line[n]..spc or spc
            end
            n=n+1
        end
    end

    for i=1,#line do
        print(line[i])
    end

end

find_min_max()
create_massive() -- probably this function works incorrect
print_drawing()

end

m={1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,2,2,3,3,4,4} -- co-ordinates: even indexes of the array are y, others are x

draw(m) -- main function is called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawing[y]={[x]=1}` creates a new row with a single entry.

Try `drawing[y][x]=1`.

Comment: I tried to but it output an error:

    lua5.3: source_file.lua:33: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
    stack traceback:
     source_file.lua:33: in local 'create_massive'
     source_file.lua:70: in function 'draw'
     source_file.lua:77: in main chunk
     [C]: in ?

So I added `drawing[y]={}` before `drawing[y][x]=1` but it didn't help.

Comment: @ViChyavIn - `drawing[y] = drawing[y] or {}; drawing[y][x]=1`